# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, prisma

I'm having a problem when running the npx prisma migrate dev command. Docker desktop tells me that the database is running correctly on port 5432 but I still can't see the problem.
I tried to put `connect_timeout=300` to the connection string, tried many versions of postgres and docker, but I can't get it to work.
I leave you the link of the repo and photos so you can see the detail of the code.
I would greatly appreciate your help, since I have been lost for a long time with this.

Repo: https://github.com/gabrielmcreynolds/prisma-vs-typeorm/tree/master/prisma-project
Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgresprisma
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=santino2002
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Error:

> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`
> Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.

Docker ps show this:
[image]

Comment: can you run `docker ps`

Comment: Yes, I use that command and everything runs fine

Comment: Where is the `npx` command running? On your host or in another container?

Comment: @Phil I don't understand the question, npx is running in the container postreprisma, but the command npx prisma init worked correctly

Comment: I meant in what context do you run the `npx prisma migrate` command... is it running on your computer (the host) or in another Docker container (eg using a `node` image). It doesn't make sense to say that it's running in the `postreprisma` container since the `postgres` image doesn't have Node installed.

Comment: Also, how are you running the Docker image? Have you run `docker compose up` or are you using some other command? When you run `docker ps`, what does it show?

Comment: Please add complete `docker ps` output into the question. as @MicaelLevi suggested.

Comment: Add in the message what docker ps returns @Mansur

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the application and the database are running on two separate containers. So, in this case, connecting to `localhost:5432` from the application container will try to connect to 5432 port within that container and not in the docker host's localhost.
To connect to database from the application container, use `postgres:5432` (If they are on the same network) or `<dockerhost>:5432`.

Comment: I also tried that way but it doesn't work either

Comment: Is there any firewall that is blocking the connection?

Comment: Don't think of it that way. I will verify it

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the container name as HOST in the db url :

```
postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/mydb?schema=public
```

Then, the connection should work from your app, but not the migrations commands. For this, you have to execute the commands from inside the container like this (considering that your app container is called myApp) :

```
docker exec myApp npx prisma migrate dev
```

To make it simpler, you can create a script in your package.json with this command :

```
// package.json
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
      "prisma-migrate-dev": "docker exec myApp npx prisma migrate dev",
      "prisma-studio": "docker exec myApp npx prisma studio" 
   }
   ...
}
```

(If you want that the prisma studio work, you have to expose the port 5555 in the docker-compose.)

Then execute the script migration:

```
yarn prisma-migrate-dev
# OR
npm run prisma-migrate-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker ps` output is showing that your `postgres` container has no ports connected to your local network.

It should look something similiar to this on `ports` column.

```
0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp
```

But yours is just `5432/tcp`

You need to open ports for your `postgres` container.

Your `docker-compose.yml` file you posted in the question is correct. Probably you started `postgres` container with no ports first, then changed your `docker-compose.yml` file to have ports. So you just need to restart it now.

Use `docker compose down && docker compose up --build -d` to do that.

Comment: Hi, I made these changes and I get it to show me the port. But I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me
Edit: postgresql.conf

```
 sudo nano /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
```

[image]

remove # from
**listen_addresses**  or add like this

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then restart the server

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese check file .env
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/mydb?schema=public"
you fix
postgresql://:@:/?schema=

Comment: Please edit and format your answer!! While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve it's long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you could have updated the **DATABASE_URL** string in the `.env` file.

Make sure to:

1. Save the changes made in `.env` file
2. Restart Docker
3. Run `npx prisma db push` command.